# History.js URL without trailing slash doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, history.js

I'm using the [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) for URL changes without reloading. This is used on a website with product filters, where the filters are placed in the URL so the URL can be shared with the active filters.

The URL's of the website don't end on a trailing slash, so a valid URL for the site is:
`www.mysite.com/products`.

This URL would show you a list with all products an you are ably to apply filters. Applying a filters should change the URL to:

`www.mysite.com/products/?filter1=2,4,6&filter2=4`

This works in FireFox, Chrome, IE11. In IE9 however, it fails on the trailing slash. The URL in IE9 is change to:

`www.mysite.com/products#products?filter1=2,4,6&filter2=4`

It seems that it sees `product` as a parameter, in stead of a part of the URL. If I manually add a trailing slash behind the URL, it works fine in IE9.

Base URL: `www.mysite.com/products/` will be `www.mysite.com/products/?filter1=2,4,6&filter2=4` when using the history.js, even in IE9.

So summary:
Adding a trailing slash at the end of the base URL fixes the problem. But I don't want to add that last trailing slash, the history.js should do that. How would that be accomplished?

**EDIT**

I think the problem is in this part of the code, th

```
var basePageUrl = (History.getLocationHref()).replace(/[#\?].*/,'').replace(/[^\/]+$/,function(part,index,string){
  return (/[^\/]$/).test(part) ? '' : part;
}).replace(/\/+$/,'')+'/';
```

This script turns this baseURL: `www.mysite.com/products`
into: `www.mysite.com`

I'm not that strong in regex, so actually have no idea what the regex does in this example.

Comment: This seems to be a bug, because the second replace makes no sense at all at first glance.

Comment: At the moment I changes the url to fix the problem. Needed to write some 301 redirect...

Answer (score 0):

in the History.getPageUrl function, I've added this line

```
//Yoni's hack to not have trailing slash
        if (pageUrl.substr(pageUrl.length - 1, 1) == '/') {
            pageUrl = pageUrl.substr(0, pageUrl.length - 1);
        }
```

just before the

```
return pageUrl;
```

In Symfony 2 we are not using trailing slash, so there is never use of it, and it's then a good condition, if you need both possibilities, you have to handle it in another way probably